# How to Show a PopOver always portrait with different interface orientations?

Tags: objective-c

I have blocked  interface orientation by this code.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"landsape");
     }
        return NO;
     }
```

i am using a popover to point to a button upward direction.

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button bounds] inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

It is is correct for portait mode.
My question is How to Show the popover always upward with respect to portait mode of screen?
If anyone have any idea please help...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if u always want to use portrait mode than replace your method with following one

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
   }
```